# Is my MVC approach correct?

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm writing an app in MVC 5 right now. I've made MVC app(for iOS) some time ago, but honestly i'm a little bit confused right now. I tried to find some info about this pattern, but it seems that there are many approaches.

My app uses external database operating on JSON format. I have bunch of methods in Api class that return objects filled with data from database. In my opinion this Api class is basically model, but i am not sure.

Model:

```
//Model
public class UserModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }

}
```

Api class(Model?):

```
public class Api
{
    public UserModel GetUserData()
    {
        UserModel model = new UserModel();
        //code connecting to DB and filling UserModel object

        return model;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
//Controller
public ActionResult Index ()
{
    UserModel model = new UserModel();
    Api api = new Api();
    model = api.GetUserData();

    return View(model);
}
```

View:

```
@*View*@

@model application.Models.UserModel

@Model.Name
@Model.Lastname
```

And my last question. Where should i put methods like loginuser, delete user:

```
public void DeleteUser(UserModel model)
{
    //code deleting user 
}
```

Should it go to model or controller? What i think is - if it will be used multiple times in different places i should put it in model, otherwise it should go to controller.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Api class is not a model, the model classes must be entities of your domain. Your domain is the core of your business, for example, if your are making a School Application, your models/entities are: Student, Teacher, Discipline ...

So your Api belongs to your infrasctucture layer, and all classes with database access responsability.

Your controller's must only orchestrate the workflow, for example:

```
private readonly api;

public HomeController()
{
    this.api = new Api();
}

public ActionResult Index ()
{
    var model = api.GetUserData();
    return View(model);
}
```

Your Api probably will be used on other Actions, so you can make a private field and initialize it from constructor. But the best approach is to use an IoC container.

The LoginUser must be a action on your Controller, but the business rule could be on other layer of your project, so it can be reusable. For example:

```
public ActionResult Login(string login, string password)
{
    var user = api.GetUserByLogin(login);

    if(user == null)
    {
        ViewBag.ErrorMsg = "There is no user with this login";
        return View();
    }

    //userService is a class responsible for business rules for users
    var isSuccess = userService.LoginUser(login, password);

    if(isSuccess)
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

    ViewBag.ErrorMsg = "Password is incorrect";
    return View();
}
```

Be careful because the ASP.NET MVC still have the concept of ViewModels. That are classes where we use to show data in our Views. In our school application, for example, we could have a View which is necessary to show a Discipline with all students enrolled, and what professor. So we need to use information of 3 entities, in that case we make a ViewModel to show all this information together.

Comment: Yes i am familiar with ViewModel concept. Thank you for explanation.